# NSNotificationService only working if I make notification global

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsnotificationcenter

I have a simple setup.

I have a 'TripService' and a 'TripViewController'.  When something changes in the trip service, such as the distance it should fire a notification, so that anyone interested should be notified, in this case the view controller.

Problem happens when I trigger the notification tied to an object, so i put:

```
[NSNotification notificationWithName:TRIPSERVICEDISTANCECHANGE 
                              object:self 
                            userInfo:distanceInfo];
```

and listen for it with

```
[notificationCenter addObserver:self
                       selector:@selector(distanceChanged:)
                           name:TRIPSERVICEDISTANCECHANGE
                         object:self.tripRecorder];
```

In this case I trigger it but nothing distanceChanged never gets fired.

If I replace both 'object' values with nil then this works.

The strange thing is this works Fine if I run the app in debug mode and step through the code.

Comment: Double check that object in addObserver is actually the same object that's posting the notification. The object parameter says "I only want to hear from this specific object", so it seems like that's where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code:

```
[notificationCenter addObserver:self
                   selector:@selector(distanceChanged:)
                       name:TRIPSERVICEDISTANCECHANGE
                     object:self.tripRecorder];
```

the argument:
`object:self.tripRecorder` tells the notification center to only deliver `TRIPSERVICEDISTANCECHANGE` notifications to `self` that are sent from `self.tripRecorder`. If the notifications are being delivered when `object:` is set to `nil`, that tells me that `self.tripRecorder` may not be the object sending the notification. However, you also say that the code works if you step through the program with the debugger. That sounds like an object-lifetime issue (The notification object is being destroyed before the notification center can process/deliver the notification). `notificationWithName:` returns an autoreleased object, is it possible this object is being released at the end of the method in which it is created?

Comment: I deleted it and did it over and it worked , so it must have pointed to the wrong address..... weird